# Describing product of diagonal terms in Smith normal form in term of minors

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ integer matrix. Then $A$ is equivalent to a matrix with diagonal entries $d_1,d_1,\dots,d_n,$ where $0<d_i\mid d_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1.$ I'm asked to describe the product $d_1d_2\cdots d_k$ in terms of the minors of $A.$ I'm assuming it will be equal to the gcd of all the $k$-by-$k$ minors of $A,$ because $d_1$ is the gcd of all the entries of $A,$ and $d_1d_2\cdots d_n$ is the determinant of $A.$ However, I'm not sure how can I prove this. I'm guessing that induction is the way to go here, and tried showing $d_1d_2$ is the gcd of all the 2-by-2 minors of $A.$ I know that
$$
A\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
  d_1 &\\
  & A_1\\
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
  d_1 &  &  \\
   & d_2 &  \\
   &  & A_3
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are block matrices, $d_1$ is the gcd of all entries of $A,$ and $d_2$ is the gcd of all entries of $A_1.$ Can I use this to prove my claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall how one gets the SNF of a matrix over $\mathbb Z$: by elementary transformations. These have the well known property of leaving the minors unchanged (up to a sign), so the ideal generated by the $k\times k$-minors of $A$ are equals the corresponding ideal of the SNF of $A$.